# VOLTTRON BACnet proxy on different port other than 47808

Tags: networking, volttron, bacnet

Is it possible setup the BACnet Proxy Agent to scrape BACnet devices on a different UDP Port other than the typical 47808 which is default for BACnet?

This is the VOLTTRON [BACnet Proxy Agent config file](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/tree/main/services/core/BACnetProxy#agent-configuration), does it support specifying different UDP ports?

```
{
    "device_address": "10.0.2.15",
    "max_apdu_length": 1024,
    "object_id": 599,
    "object_name": "Volttron BACnet driver",
    "vendor_id": 15,
    "segmentation_supported": "segmentedBoth"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your IP address of the device running VOLTTRON for the BACnet proxy in the format of IP, subnet in CIDAR notation, and port number. Like this:

`"device_address": "10.0.2.15/24:47820"`

Comment: It might depend upon whether the request is a UDP(v4) 'Broadcast' or directed/'Unicast' - VLANs and routers do not forward-on Broadcasts; e.g. a 'Who-Is' versus a 'Read-Property' service request.

So even with the right address format, there might still be an issue.

Comment: Hi, could you test that by plugging into the OT network and running a BACnet scan tool for a discovery "who-is" and just try out different UDP ports thru the scan tool other than 47808 to see what comes up? Its a campus scenario of lots of buildings where it seems like the IT set it up on a Flat network where then each building has a unique UDP port assigned to it and I think a BBMD. Thanks for any tips

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'OT' network?  You could do, but I'm wondering if the 'NMap' tool instead (even without using the BACnet NSE script) would show you more easily what port # (that is close to the BACnet default of 47808/0xBAC) is open (listening/filtering) for each building.  What's this for, you're not a student trying to hack the college campus, are you (?).

Comment: The fact that it's all on the same VLAN, sounds wrong (/potentially troublesome) already.  Surely you can ask them for the required info if this is an official collaboration (- otherwise you probably shouldn't be prodding their network until you've been given a formal go-ahead).